# Help with naming

Tags: magic, names

## Name suggestions

So I have a magic system that's based on creating and manipulating certain "fields" and need some help with names for the magic and the users. I don't want to call them wizards on just create a word. For example, channelers and channeling from wheel of time. I want to describe what they do without making it sound generic with words like magic, or druid. Mistborn and Allomancy from the Mistborn books by Brandon Sanderson would another good example. If you have any ideas with anything related to fields/dominions i would appreciate it

### Quick description of what a field is:

Imagine fields and space were certain aspects that can be controlled by the user. For example, I can make a field around me that changes the passage of time within the field so that time within the "bubble" becomes slower. You could also change other things, like temperature, gravity, etc.

Comment: You'll find that naming is regarded as off-topic as it invariably relies on opinions rather than any objective criteria. Take a look at our [list of question types](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types) which clues you up with practical examples of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Questions are often closed if there is no objective way to decide which answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

**Tensors**

In physics a tensor describes the intensity and direction of a field. For example how the field of pressure varies as we change the depth of water; or the gravitational field which controls what paths light travels.

In gravitation we often pretend gravity is like a rubber sheet; heavy objects push the sheet down, adding **tension**, and smaller objects are pulled into the gravity wells.

It makes sense if people who add or release tension in these fields are also called **tensors**. The magic in this universe is called **Tension**.

For example a tensor might tighten the time field near themselves. This makes time pass quickly  nearby and the result is super speed from an outsider's point of view. Alternately they can loosen the time field so they can quickly travel into the future.

Comment: In addition, they could be said to be multi dimensional. 

Comment: the explanation is 10/10 but tensor seems such a weird name XD. imagine a scene were someone is like "carefull hes a tensor!" XD its sounds so ridiculous

Comment: *"Tenser," said the tensor. "Tenser," said the tensor. "Tension, apprehension, and dissension have begun."* (Alfred Bester, *The Demolished Man*)

Comment: So yes, perhaps a silly name, but one with a *pedigree*, and that makes all the difference!

Comment: @MiguelSimões To make it less silly I imagine most people will pronounce it "tenser" which is already an English word. Similar to how in Star Trek people often say "sensers" instead of "sensORS". "Captain I'm picking something up on long range sensors".

Comment: @Cadence in fact I think you have to pronounce "tensor" as "tenser" for that rhyme to rhyme.

Comment: @MiguelSimões If magic is called "tension" then it is natural to call a wizard a "tenser". In fact that name also has some pedigree from "Tensor's Floating Disk" from D&D.